# Is there a JWPlayer + Wowza, cross browser solution?

Tags: firefox, jwplayer, wowza

Having spend the last couple of days reading the manuals, watching videos and reading through the forum, I can honestly I have no idea what I'm doing.

My basic requirement is to display a video on a web page so that it works in all major browsers.

Easy in Chrome, not so easy in anything else it seems.

For example Firefox will say 'Error loading player, No playable sources available', or if I add more sources it simple prompts me to select a video player on my local machine and proceeds to download the file.

Here is where I'm at right now, of-course it does not work.

```
jwplayer("playerOMLNJWgiRjbu").setup({
"sources": [
{ "file": "rtmp://video.newnrg.com:1935/vod/mp4:sample.mp4"},
{ "file": "http://video.newnrg.com:1935/vod/mp4:sample.mp4/manifest.mpd" },
{ "file": "http://video.newnrg.com:1935/vod/mp4:sample.mp4/playlist.m3u8"},
{ "file": "http://video.newnrg.com:1935/vod/mp4:sample.mp4/manifest.f4m"},
{ "file": "rtsp://video.newnrg.com:1935/vod/sample.mp4" }
],
"rtmp": {
"bufferlength": 5
},
"primary": "flash",
"modes": [
{ "type": "flash", "src": "/app/src/jwplayer/jwplayer.flash.swf" }
]
});
```

HTTP tests:

```
rtmp://video.newnrg.com:1935/vod/mp4:sample.mp4 (200)
http://video.newnrg.com:1935/vod/mp4:sample.mp4/manifest.mpd (200)
http://video.newnrg.com:1935/vod/mp4.../playlist.m3u8 (200)
http://video.newnrg.com:1935/vod/mp4...4/manifest.f4m (200)
rtsp://video.newnrg.com:1935/vod/sample.mp4 (200)
```

In firefox when rtsp://video.newnrg.com:1935/vod/sample.mp4 is used it asks for a locally installed player to play the video file, yet pasting this URL into the browser address bar works.

I've looked at the wowza homepage to attempt to dissect how this library is being used.

Wowza config:

(on) MPEG-DASH
(on) Apple HLS
(on) Adobe RTMP
(on) Adobe HDS
(on) Microsoft Smooth Streaming
(on) RTSP/RTP

From my perspective I've certainly struggled to get to this point, and have the following questions.

1. Which is the preferred client side player, with a decent JavaScript API,
2. I like the JWPlayer api, so can it be used? and what is best practice in easy to follow steps 1, 2, 3.

Comment: Can I see where you are running this with the player?

Comment: I put this page quickly on a web-server I have handy, however I have been testing on my local machine, via a web address mapped to 127.0.0.1 in my hosts file.

http://144.76.118.149/video_test.html

Comment: have you installed flash player ?

Comment: This is running fine, but you need Flash installed since this is RTMP.

Comment: Thanks I think you are right.

I have added quite a lot of functionality to the test page to workout under what circumstances videos are failing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using jwplayer 6.11 video not Play on ipad](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27620483/using-jwplayer-6-11-video-not-play-on-ipad)